# Is there a way to force request in WSO2 API Manager for HTTP DELETE?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

From what I gather from the web is that the WSO2 API Gateway Manager drops the Request Payload in an HTTP DELETE operation.
Does anybody know if there is any kind of a workaround or a config change in the ESB that could make it possible.

Like there are HTTP Properties e.g. FORCE_POST_PUT_NOBODY to force no body in POST/PUT operations. Any help/suggestions/experiences will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have any workaround to solve this problem.

WSO2 API Manager depends on Apache HttpComponents/HttpCore library for this functionality and this issue is fixed in their 5.0 which isn't released yet.

You can find the JIRA [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCORE-380) reported against httpCode library.

Comment: That's great - thanks !! Look forward to V5.0. Thanks.